# Dynamic font-resizing for fixed width element that corresponds with another div

Tags: jquery, css, fixed-width

I'm looking for a solution that will automatically re-size some text in a fixed width div to fit.

The only tricky thing is that on some of them, I need the both of the font sizes to match the smallest size (to ensure that both of the elements are always the same size.)  I was thinking this could be achieved by giving them the same class name or something to indicate correlation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, given a bunch of inputs and outputs:

```
<div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" value="John Smith">
    <input type="text" value="Jane Doe">
</div>

<ul class="outputs">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Use this function to bind the outputs to the inputs:

```
function sync( inputs, outputs ) {
    var max_width, max_size, curr_size;

    function curr_max_width() {
        return Math.max.apply( null, $( outputs ).map( function () {
            return $( this ).width();
        }).get() );
    }

    outputs = $( outputs ).wrapInner( '<span />' ).children().get();
    max_width = $( outputs ).parent().width();
    max_size = parseInt( $( outputs ).css( 'font-size' ), 10 );

    $( inputs ).bind( 'keyup change', function ( e ) {      
        $( outputs ).text( function ( i ) {
            return $( inputs ).eq( i ).val();
        });

        curr_size = 0;        
        do {
            curr_size += 1;
            $( outputs ).css({ 'font-size': curr_size + 'px' });
        } while ( curr_max_width() < max_width && curr_size < max_size );

        $( outputs ).css({ 'font-size': ( curr_size - 1 ) + 'px' });
    }).triggerHandler( 'change' );
}
```

Usage:

```
var inputs = $( 'input:text', '.inputs' ).get();
var outputs = $( 'li', '.outputs' ).get();

sync( inputs, outputs );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/HF4W4/18/

So, the `sync` function expects an array of `<input>` elements as the first argument and an array of block elements as the second argument. Notice that the output elements should have `white-space: nowrap` set. The `sync` function inner-wraps the output elements in `<span>` elements, so that it can read the width of the content.

Answer (score 1):

maybe hide the div to begin with and using jquery incrementally increase the font size until your box starts increasing? The trick is to start with the min-height and min-width value.

```
<div id="myBox" style="min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px;"></div>

var startWidth = $('#mybox').css('width');
var fontSize = 5;
while($('#mybox').css('width') != startWidth)
{
  fontSize++;
  $('#mybox').css('font-size',fontSize+'px');
}
```

Completely untested, but you should get the idea?